# Filter contacts by account

Tags: contacts, people-app, contact-groups

I have a number of mail accounts on my Samsung Tablet. Contacts stored online are synced with the local tablet contacts and visible in the stock Android `Contact` app.

As different accounts are connected with different task/activities, I would like to filter contacts by account.

Is there a way in the stock contact app to display only contacts for a given account? 
If not, is it possible to achieve this with a different app?

My Android version is 3.2.

Comment: Which Samsung tablet? Which version of the OS? The People app for each might be different.

Comment: @AlEverett: My Android version is 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Unless munged by Samsung, while in the People app you should be able to go to **menu** → **Contacts to display** and then choose the account for which you want to see contacts. There's even a "Customize" option which allows one to, for instance, only display contacts from certain of an account's contact groups.

Comment: probably not in Android3.2

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Can't help you there. I never had a device with 3.x.